# How to implement a style where the picture inside the Card Media will somehow pop out or like it will hover above?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is the sample code of the Card from material-ui. How can I make the picture inside the card media to somehow pop out a bit when the mouse hovers on it? Or like a zoom once the mouse hovers on that picture

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
});

export default function MediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'hover' mediaquery. Here you can find an example that I made base on your code [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-field-ttjlb?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
    "&:hover": {
      transform: "scale(1.5)"
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="assets/image.png"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: @JenJennie you may also want to add css `transition` to make sure the effect runs smoothly.

Comment: @NearHuscarl is right add a `transition: "1s"` or similar intervall to the media,outside the '&:hover' part for a smooth transition effect. I updated it in the sandbox code it looks defenitly nicer.